# "Wix booking", how to add variations to an offered service (e.g. different durations, discounts, ...)

Tags: wix

I have a Wix "Booking" shop for my various services (30 different services).

I want to offer choices / variations. Every kind of service can have:

- 3 different durations (1, 2 or 3 hours)
- optional additions ("extra cheese", "outdoors/indoors", ...)

Currently, this is Not available.

Consequently, I have to **duplicate** each service x 3-4 times, i.e. 120 different services, which is impossible to manage.

Am I missing some options?  Can I add "options" via Dev API?

Comment: This may not get answerd quickly because none of our regulars have much experience with Wix as far as I know.   I usually recommend migrating to a different web host because Wix has severe limitations.  It is usually easier to implement advanced website features other platforms.

Comment: like @StephenOstermiller said, plus you get trapped in the Wix ecosystem and can't export your site if you decide to change to a new platform.

Comment: we're aware of the math :) the website is already build. We might redirect products to an external shop via a subdomain, though.